# Light source that withstands extreme conditions

Tags: led, light, thermal, standard

I am designing an aircraft obstruction light, and Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) requires crazy requirements for their standards. One standard goes as following (From FAA AC 150/5345-43H):

> 4.2.2 High temperature test
>
> 1... The equipment must be subjected to a constant temperature of **+130F (+55C)** for 4 hours after equipment temperature stabilization and be operated throughout the test.
>
> 4.2.3 Low temperature test
>
> 1... The equipment must be placed in a chamber that maintains a temperature of **-67 degrees F (-55 C)** for shipping/storage requirements and **-40 F (-40 C)** for equipment operational requirements.

Does such a light source exist in this world? Do they have a specific name? My searches on Google was misleading so far, "military grade led" led me to torches, "cold led" led me to cool-white LEDs.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the temperature requirements go the storage temperature (-40°C vs. -55°C) is the only real issue.

For cold operating temperature LEDs make great heat sources.

+55°C is not that difficult to achieve.

Based on the little information I have gained in your comments, it  appears you are in this over your head.

In response to this comment...

> To check I wasn't going insane, I opened a standard LED datasheet,
>   such as the 150066SV74000 from WURTH. It states temperature range of
>   "-40C to +85C". So your requirement is easily met. -- @Puffafish

you said...

> looks like these may be my best option. Thank you

First off -40°C does not meet the specs. 
This LED is only 55 mcd.
How are you going to meet the daytime requirement of 270,000,000 mcd?
What do you know about the luminosity of red LEDs?
What do you know about and LED's view angle and how it affects intensity?

---

> ...from what I understand from 4.2.2 "equipment temperature
>   stabilization" they first heat the product, then turn it on. I may be
>   wrong though

Clearly you have no concept of environmental testing. And environmental testing is one of the easiest things to understand in the FAA spec.

---

Your biggest challenge would be the optics.
Have you noticed how obstruction lights have that cover with horizontal ribbing?
Do you understand why?
Notice the details.  They don't do that to make it look nice.

[image]

---

Do you understand the education and experience required to take a light source and design these optics?

---

How are you going to achieve the 3° to 7° vertical beam spread?

[image]

---

What is your budget for this project?
I would be very impressed if anyone could do this for less than $100,000.

---

Notice at the beginning of chapter 4 of [AC 150/5345-43H](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5345-43GH.pdf):  *"Airport Lighting Equipment Certification Program"*

Notice all the qualification tests required?  Do you know how much it costs to have each of these tests done by an FAA qualified testing laboratory?

Comment: Thank you for your opinions. To be honest this will be my first outdoor design, so I am "a little" inexperienced about the testing process. Hopefully I will learn though.

Comment: I don't think you understand the magnitude and expense of the testing.  This is not easy stuff.   I have serious doubt you have the ability to understand much less implement the required optics and photometrics.  Very complex.   Very time consuming.  Very expensive.